# Why ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail() return null when get video from gallery

Tags: java, android

I have a video from gallery and I need get its thumbnail. I use ThumbnailUtils class for this purpose, but it returns null instead of expected Bitmap.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==GalleryPick  &&  resultCode==RESULT_OK  &&  data!=null)
    {
        Uri resultUri = data.getData();

        Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(resultUri.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);


        Glide.with(this).load(thumb).into(videoView);

    }


}
```

I also try below code but it doesn't work

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==GalleryPick  &&  resultCode==RESULT_OK  &&  data!=null)
    {
        Uri resultUri = data.getData();

        File file = new File(resultUri.getPath()); //

        Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND); //


        Glide.with(this).load(thumb).into(videoView);

    }


}
```